# Last value per column in group, one row per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This should be simple but for some reason I'm stuck.  Consider the following data:

```
KEY1  KEY2  COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------------------------
1     1     A       7       (null)
1     2     A       8       (null)
1     3     (null)  7       (null)
2     2     (null)  (null)  4
2     4     B       6       (null)
3     1     A       B       (null)
```

(KEY1 is the Id, KEY2 is the generation, and there are actually about 30 data columns but I'm only listing 3 here for simplicity.)

I want to get one row per Id, and for each column get the last non-null value.  In other words...

```
KEY1  COL1    COL2    COL3
----------------------------
1     A       7       (null)
2     B       6       4
3     A       B       (null)
```

I tried the following but it seems to do nothing other than echo out all my rows.

```
SELECT key1,
       LAST_VALUE(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY key2 ASC) AS col1,
       LAST_VALUE(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY key2 ASC) AS col2,
       LAST_VALUE(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY key2 ASC) AS col3
    FROM test1
```

(And this is for SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server Express.)

Comment: This type of table structure is going to require a very expensive and/or complex query to get the data that you're asking for. You should strongly consider normalizing this table so that you can right much simpler queries and faster queries.

Comment: LAST_VALUE(col1 Ignore null)?

Comment: That would be for Oracle, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not (yet) support the `IGNORE NULL` option on window functions.  One method is to use conditional aggregation.  This requires an intelligent generation of sequence numbers for the columns, to ensure that the value "1" for the sequence is assigned to non-NULL values.

Here is a query that should do this:

```
select t1.key1,
       max(case when seqnum1 = 1 then col1 end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum2 = 1 then col2 end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum3 = 1 then col3 end) as col13
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key1
                                order by (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         key2 desc
                               ) as seqnum1,
             row_number() over (partition by key1
                                order by (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         key2 desc
                               ) as seqnum2,
             row_number() over (partition by key1
                                order by (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         key2 desc
                               ) as seqnum3
      from test1 t1
     ) t1
group by t1.key1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gets the highest non-null value and I need the last non-null value.

Comment: @PeterTrevor . . . It does *not* get the highest non-NULL value (at least it shouldn't).  The `max()` is operating on only one value because of the condition.  One one row has a sequence number of 1 for any given column, which should be the last non-NULL value based on the `order by`.

Comment: . . Sorry, I was hoping this solution would work as it is the cheaper of the two answers.  But when I copy-n-paste this query, for `key1=1` I'm getting `col2=8.`  I wanted `col2=7.`  (All other values are correct.)  I think what is happening is the query is setting seqnumN to 1 for **all** non-null values, not just the first desc one found.

Comment: (Unrelated note: Is there yet another browser quirk that stops me saving a comment that starts with a commenter's name?  GL: If you got three replies it's because I tried to post the above comment three times.)

Comment: @PeterTrevor . . . I'm sorry about that.  I have no idea where the `is not null` came from in the conditional aggregation.  It should be (and I changed it to) `seqnum = 1` for each of the variables.

Comment: Great.  That does it.  Switching answer as this is significantly cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the requirements correctly, shouldn't this work? Might be quite expensive depending on the amount of data / columns.

```
select
   key1,
   (select top 1 col1 from test1 t2 where t.key1 = t2.key1 and col1 is not null order by key2 desc) as col1,
   (select top 1 col2 from test1 t2 where t.key1 = t2.key1 and col2 is not null order by key2 desc) as col2,
   (select top 1 col3 from test1 t2 where t.key1 = t2.key1 and col3 is not null order by key2 desc) as col3
from 
   (select distinct key1 from test1) t
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to works.  I'll have to scale it up now and see what the performance hit is like.